# Remove top navigation bar for certain screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way of removing the top navigation bar for specific screens only? I am using react-navigation.

I already tried the following:

```
header: { visible: false }
```

but it only hides the navbar. The space of the navbar is still cannot be used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried "header: null" instead? I used that to not show header in mine.

Comment: Yeah that does it, but how about to remove it only on certain screens?

Comment: The way I did it is to have navigationOptions for each screen. See my answer below for example.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is an example of how I did mine using StackNavigator:

```
const stackN = StackNavigator({
    Screen1 : {
      screen: Screen1,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      }
    },
    Home : {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        title: 'Home',
        headerStyle: styles.headerStyle,
        headerTitle: <Text>Home</Text>,
        headerLeft : null,
        headerRight: null,
      })
    }, 
}, {headerMode: 'screen'})
```

So every screen have their own navigationOptions instead. There may be a way to share navigationOptions, but I haven't looked into it at the moment.

Comment: Would be better if there's a way for the navigationOptions to be shared. I only want the navigation removed on the login and splash screen, the others it will be displayed.

Comment: After testing, your answer also satisfies the need of removing the navigation on certain views. What you do is just specify a navigation option on those certain views and put the `header: null` property.

Comment: what if I need to show Status Bar? If I add StatusBar component. its not showing

Answer (score 54):

I use the `headerShown` flag like this:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
 import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
 import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

 import Welcome from "./compenents/Welcome";
 import Home from "./compenents/Home";

 const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
   return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
           <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
           <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
options={{ headerShown: false }}
```

you are done .. have a nice day

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import NewsDetailScreen from "./screens/NewsDetailScreen";
import React from "react";
    
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

const HomeScreenStack = () => {
  return (
<HomeStack.Navigator >
  <HomeStack.Screen
    name="homeScreen"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{ title: "Home" }}
  />
  <HomeStack.Screen
    name="newsDetailScreen"
    component={NewsDetailScreen}
    options={{
      title: "News Detail",
      headerShown:false
    }}
  />
</HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default HomeScreenStack;
```

Answer (score 4):

When using createStackNavigator then top navigation bar can be removed as below.

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: MainTabNavigator }, { headerMode: 'none' });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `navigationOptions: { header: null }` to remove the top navigation bar.

Sample Code:

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import {Login} from './app/components/login/Login';
import {Register} from './app/components/register/Register';
import {Home} from './app/components/home/Home';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Login: { 
                  screen: Login,
                  navigationOptions: {
                    header: null,
                  }
               },
        Register: { 
                    screen: Register, 
                    navigationOptions: {
                      header: null,
                    }  
                  },
        Home: { 
                screen: Home, 
                navigationOptions: {
                  header: null,
                }
              },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Login"
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use **navigationOptions: { headerShown: false }**  instead of **navigationOptions: { header: null }** to remove the top navigation bar.

Answer (score 3):

"headerShown : false " in the latest React Native version

Comment: Was answered already below. Repeating answers does not make sense.

Comment: this one is much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

2020 => v5 :

to delete title in all screens

```
Stack.Navigator.defaultProps = {
    headerMode: 'none',
};
```